# Unable to pass array in function in c# (Byte [ ])

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, byte

In function `aes_encrypt()` I want to pass only first 16 elements of an array not whole array. I am new to C#. I am getting an error that **"Cannot Convert from byte to byte []"**

```
byte[][] packet = new byte[12][];
private static byte[] key_dec_pswd = new byte[16];
for (int loop = 0; loop < noofbyte; loop++)
{
   packet[addr / 512][addr % 512 + 4 + loop] = Convert.ToByte(RawDataLine.Substring((9 + (loop * 2)), 2), 16);
}
int j = packet[i].Length;
byte[] tmpPacket = new byte[j];

for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
{
   tmpPacket[k] = packet[i][k];
}

aes_encrypt(tmpPacket[16], key_dec_pswd); //Getting Error here. Cannot Convert from byte to byte []

public static void aes_encrypt(byte[] chlng_byte, byte[] key)
{
   aes128_encrypt(chlng_byte, key);
}
```

Comment: What is the datatype of "key_dec_pswd"? it's not explicit in your code

Comment: private static byte[] key_dec_pswd = new byte[16];

Answer (score 2):

Change

```cs
aes_encrypt(tmpPacket[16], key_dec_pswd);
```

to

```cs
aes_encrypt(tmpPacket, key_dec_pswd);
```

`tmpPacket[16]` passes only `byte` 16 into the function instead of the intended array and thus the error.

You can also simplify the byte array copy from:

```cs
int j = packet[i].Length;
byte[] tmpPacket = new byte[j];

for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
{
   tmpPacket[k] = packet[i][k];
}
```

to:

```cs
var tmpPacket = packet[i].ToArray();
```

This does the allocation and copy all in one.

Comment: The error is gone. How do I increase the tmpPacket pointer by 16 bytes. The function aes_encrypt encrypts only 16 bytes. After first 16 bytes encryption, how do I move to next 16 bytes and so on. The total length of packet[i] is 518 bytes.